# Integrity constraint violation when try to update two models without other model in Controller update function in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

working with Laravel 9 and I have following Controller Function to Update One to Many Relationship Models Employee, Title and Salary. when I try to update one or two models without other models it is generated following error message
EmployeeController

```
public function updateEmployee(Request $request, $id)
{
    $employee = Employee::find($id);

    if (is_null($employee)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Employee not found'], 404);
    }

    // Update employee information
    $employee->update([
        'first_name' => $request->input('first_name')
       ]);

    // Update related titles
    $employee->titles->update([
        'title' => $request->input('title')
       ]);

    // Update related salaries
    $employee->salaries->update([
        'salary' => $request->input('salary')
       ]);
return response($employee, 200);
}
```

and my api route is following

```
Route::put('updateEmployee/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@updateEmployee');
```

Employee Model

```
public function titles(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Title::class, 'emp_no');
}

public function salaries(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Salary::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

Salary Model

```
public function employee(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

Title Model

```
public function employee(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

but when I try update using postman Employee and Salary Models data I got following error message
`Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column &#039;title&#039; cannot be null (SQL: update` titles`set`title`= ? where`titles`.`emp_no`= 10 and`titles`.`emp_no`is not null) in file F:\2023\code\2023\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 760`
what is this problem and how could I fix this problem?

Comment: It would seem that your input does not have a `title` and your database schema doesn't allow that a column is created with a value of `null`.

Comment: Insufficient context to assess the problem. Can you please share the request you're passing in Postman?

Comment: @shahalpk postman columns names are 'first_name', 'salary', 'title' request is `http://localhost:8000/api/updateEmployee/10?first_name=makushi&salary=85200`

Comment: @Repox that is why I need I need update Employee and Salary Models using this request without Title Model

Comment: Well, you should provide the existing title if you want to keep the title. Your logic right now tries to update the title with a null value. So either provide the same title before or remove the the title from your update process, if you don't need to update it.

Comment: @Repox yes if I insert values to title column it is working fine. but in this case I need update only Employee and Salaries tables only not any update in titles table

Comment: You (or your other account???) keep asking the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77217702/how-to-validate-controller-update-function-models-values-in-laravel-9. You were told you need to validate your input, but you made no attempt to do so. You need to stop spamming this question and attempt to solve your own issues **before** asking for help on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the added comments, it apparent that you're using the controller without sending the `title` value.

That means that with your current logic, you are defaulting the input to a `null` value and your code will accordingly set your `title` value to `null`, a value not being accepted by your database schema.

You can optionally provide the original value of the title in your request body or conditionally check if the value is supplied.

A suggestion based on the latter would look something like this:

```php
public function updateEmployee(Request $request, $id)
{
    $employee = Employee::find($id);

    if (is_null($employee)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Employee not found'], 404);
    }

    // Update employee information
    $employee->update([
        'first_name' => $request->input('first_name')
       ]);

    // Update related titles
    if($request->input('title')) {
        $employee->titles->update([
            'title' => $request->input('title')
         ]);
    }
    // Update related salaries
    $employee->salaries->update([
        'salary' => $request->input('salary')
       ]);
return response($employee, 200);
}
```

But you could actually smarten this up by, simply by utilizing Laravel's features a bit better:

By using Route Model Bindind, you can shave off your manual 404 handling:

```php
Route::get('path/{employee}', [YourController::class, 'updateEmployee']);
```

Now you can bind the model to your controller method and if the employee cannot be found, Laravel automatically throws a 404.

```php
public function updateEmployee(Request $request, Employee $employee)
{

    // Validate input and allow nullable input we skip:
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'first_name' => 'nullable|string',
        'title' => 'nullable|string',
        'salary' => 'nullable|decimal:2',
    ]);

    //Update non-null values provided on your model:
    foreach ($validatedData as $key => $value) {
        $employee->{$key} = $value;
    }

    $employee->update();
    $employee->refesh();

    return response($employee, 200);
}
```

Comment: how could write postman request for `Route::get('path/{employee}', [YourController::class, 'updateEmployee']);`

Comment: @amaruwakoi I'm sorry, but I don't use Postman, but it should work exactly as before where you were passing the ID of the Model.